# cross-compiling a scala compiler plugin doesn't detect method unsupported in 2.10

Tags: scala

My library project cross compiles to both scala 2.11 and 2.10 without errors. I publish it locally with `+publishLocal`, and consume it in other projects. When used in a 2.10 project, my artifact crashes over a method that isn't available at runtime:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: `scala.tools.nsc.Global.showRaw(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/reflect/api/Printers$BooleanFlag;Lscala/reflect/api/Printers$BooleanFlag;Lscala/reflect/api/Printers$BooleanFlag;Lscala/reflect/api/Printers$BooleanFlag;)Ljava/lang/String;`

Can this discrepancy for 2.10 runtime typically be detected during the cross-compilation already?

My related build definitions for the library:

```
scalaVersion  := "2.11.6"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4", "2.11.6")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value % "provided"
)
```

It's a compiler plugin, hence the use of "provided" for the scala compiler dependency. Just curious how can it (seemingly) slip through the compilation phase.